# Formula or pattern to find irreducible polynomials over $GF(2)$ and $GF(3)$

Tags: irreducible-polynomials

I have looked at many websites and forums and none were really that helpful. 
So my question is, is there an easy way such as a formula or pattern that you can create an irreducible polynomial over $GF(2)$ or $GF(3)$. I know that $x^2+x+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $GF(2)$. But

> How can you tell when the polynomial is longer such as $x^5 +x^3 + x^2 +1$ if it is an irreducible polynomial over $GF(2)$ or $GF(3)$.

I get what an irreducible polynomial is but I want an easy way to verify.

Comment: Why do you think an easy way should exist?  This is about as difficult as testing for prime numbers. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343450/11619). I guess it depends what you mean by *easy*:-)

Comment: @Lucian: Both your links point at questions about reducibility of polynomials in $\Bbb{Z}[x]$, so I fail to see their relevance.