# Irreducibility of $x^4+x^2+x+1$ over $\mathbb{F}_5[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Consider

$$
f(x)=x^4+x^2+x+1\in \mathbb{F}_5[x]
$$

There is a straightforward but lengthy proof that $f$ is irreducible: show that $f$ has no linear factors, then assume that it splits as a product of two quadratic factors and then derive a contradiction using the coefficients of $f$.

Is there a faster method for such a polynomial and maybe something that works for a larger class of polynomials?

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1343450/how-can-i-prove-irreducibility-of-polynomial-over-a-finite-field) you can use [Rabin's test for irreducibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Rabin.27s_test_of_irreducibility). In your case, you "just" need to show:

1. $x^4+x^2+x+1 | x^{5^4}-x$
2. $(x^4+x^2+x+1,x^{5^2}-x)=1$

You can use extended GCD to see that
$$(x^4+x^2+x+1,x^{5^4}-x) = x^4+x^2+x+1$$

and also

$$(x^4+x^2+x+1,x^{5^2}-x)=1$$

so both conditions are satisfied. As is suggested in referenced link, computer algebra systems such as Mathematica/Maple can be used effectively.