# Irreducibility of $t ^ { 4 } + t - 1$ over $\mathbb{F}_{25}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory, finite-fields

> **Problem:** Let $f ( t ) = t ^ { 4 } + t - 1 \in \mathbb { F } _ { 5 } [ t ]$, show that $f(t)$ has no roots in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$.

I tried the following: suppose $f(t)$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$, then $f(t)$ can be written as the product of either two polynomials of degree 2, or the product of two polynomials of degree 1 and 3.

Suppose the first case, thus $t ^ { 4 } + t - 1  = (t^2+at+b)(t^2+ct+d)$ for some coefficients in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$.

$$\Rightarrow t ^ { 4 } + t - 1  =  t^4 +t^3(c+a)+t^2(d+ac+b)+t(ad+bc)+bd$$

However I couldn't find a contradiction at this point

Comment: Suppose $f(t)$ has a root in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$, then $f(t)$ has a **linear** factor of degree $1$, namely $t-a$, where $a$ is the root.

Comment: Oh you're right, so the only way is to check every elements of $\mathbb{F}_{25}$?

Comment: The title is a bit off. Your polynomial being *irreducible* over $\Bbb{F}_5$ is equivalent to it *not having any zeros* in $\Bbb{F}_{25}$.

Comment: Anyway, the theory for checking irreducibility of a quartic is described [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2001927/11619).

Answer (score 3):

$t^{25}-t$ is the zero function in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$.

Then $\gcd(t^{25}-t,t^4+t-1)=1$ implies that $t^4+t-1$ has no zero in $\mathbb{F}_{25}$.