# Is $x^2+x-1\in\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ irreductible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

I have to see whether $x^2+x-1\in\mathbb{F}_3[x]$ is irreductible. One first way to see this is by checking if there exist any roots of the polynomial on the field, the problem is that I don't understand which field they are talking about; $\mathbb{F}_3[x]=\{0,1,x\}$? Or is it $\mathbb{Z}_3$? In such case there are no roots since substituing each element into the polynomial yields a result which is not congruent with $0$ (mod $3$).

Comment: $\{0,1,x\}$ is not a field, it doesn't contain $-x$ or $1+x$ or $1/x$ for instance. The field is $\Bbb F_3$, of course.

Comment: Also $\Bbb F_3[x]$ is not the set $\{0,1,x\}$. It has infinitely many elements.

Comment: You can check out this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1343450/1093844

Comment: Also check [this](https://brilliant.org/wiki/finite-fields/) out if you are confused about the structure of a finite field $\Bbb{F_{p^n}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f\in \Bbb K[X]$, with $\Bbb K$ field and $\deg f=2$ or $\deg f=3$.

Then $f$ is irreducible in $\Bbb K[X]$ iff $f$ has no roots in $\Bbb K$.

In this case, $\Bbb K= \Bbb F_3$, so you only have to check whether $0$, $1$ or $2$ are roots of $f$ to prove $f$ is irreducible.